# Does glob function require a lot of physical memory usage on a folder with 10.000 jpeg files?

Tags: php

I am noticing a high physical memory usage in the cPanel hosting environment.
To display some photos that meet some criteria, I make a heavy use of the glob function in a dir with 10.000 jpeg.

Is this a possible cause?

Thank you

Here is my code

```
<?php   

$glob = glob("imgs/".$id."*.jpg");      
if (empty($glob)) { echo'none'; } 

else {          
    foreach ($glob as $img) {

 echo $img; } 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The larger the array you have, the more memory php will consume until the `max_memory` limit is reached which will then break your code. Instead of glob use `readdir` which won't consume much:

```
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $entry)));
        // Check for extension, first 4 characters a number and 5th character underscore
        if ($ext == 'jpg' && substr($entry, 0, 5) == ($id . '_')) {
            echo "$entry\n";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated my question with my code. Can you take a look at it? Does your method allow me to use the `".$id."*.jpg"` part? I am thinking of converting it to it.

Comment: You can check the extension for the filename. Will update the code to reflect.

Comment: The folder contains only jpg files and are in the format of a 4 digit id, followed by underscore and a random name

Comment: Thank you for your updates! Please tell me, how can I make use of the `$id` instead of the 4 numbers? I am not displaying all the images that have this sequence but only the images of specific `$id` followed by `_` and a name

Comment: With this solution you will need to go through each file and check for any requirement. Unlike glob which does it the other way. Updated it so that it checks for $id_

Answer (score 1):

Yes; it is likely that you might think it's slow.

I prefer the RecursiveDirectoryIterator or the DirectoryIterator.

Here is a demonstration using RecursiveDirectoryIterator, that should print all files in all directories, for the root directory specified.

```
<?php
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.'), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($files as $name => $file) {
    echo $name . '<br />';
} 
?>
```

Edit:
After reading your comments, I have made a solution that may be more suitable for you.

```
<?php
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("."));
$files = new RegexIterator($files,'/^.+\.jpeg$/i',RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
```

The readdir solution is faster, however.

Comment: Does `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` load all the files or does it act like `readdir`. If so, it could be a better solution thank my answer.

Comment: It does not perform any I/O other than reading the file names, AFAIK.

Comment: I meant does it like `glob` does 1 I/O and puts the files into the object, or like `readdir`, does one I/O operation on each file read.